# Rebuilding my wave file with struct

Tags: python, audio, struct

My goal is to read a wave file and edit the data of it by adding a random number to each bit of data in the range of -1 to 1 with the hope of creating some distortion and then saving it as an edited wave file. I read and edit the wave file like so:

```
riffTag = fileIn.read(4)
if riffTag != 'RIFF':
    print 'not a valid RIFF file'
    exit(1)

riffLength = struct.unpack('<L', fileIn.read(4))[0]
riffType = fileIn.read(4)
if riffType != 'WAVE':
    print 'not a WAV file'
    exit(1)

# now read children
while fileIn.tell() < 8 + riffLength:
    tag = fileIn.read(4)
    length = struct.unpack('<L', fileIn.read(4))[0]

    if tag == 'fmt ':  # format element
        fmtData = fileIn.read(length)
        fmt, numChannels, sampleRate, byteRate, blockAlign, bitsPerSample = struct.unpack('<HHLLHH', fmtData)
        stHeaderFields['AudioFormat'] = fmt
        stHeaderFields['NumChannels'] = numChannels
        stHeaderFields['SampleRate'] = sampleRate
        stHeaderFields['ByteRate'] = byteRate
        stHeaderFields['BlockAlign'] = blockAlign
        stHeaderFields['BitsPerSample'] = bitsPerSample

    elif tag == 'data': # data element
        rawData = fileIn.read(length)

    else: # some other element, just skip it
        fileIn.seek(length, 1)

numChannels = stHeaderFields['NumChannels']

# some sanity checks
assert(stHeaderFields['BitsPerSample'] == 16)
assert(numChannels * stHeaderFields['BitsPerSample'] == blockAlign * 8)

samples = []
edited_samples = []

for offset in range(0, len(rawData), blockAlign):
    samples.append(struct.unpack('<h', rawData[offset:offset+blockAlign]))

for sample in samples:
    edited_samples.append(sample[0] + random.randint(-1, 1))
```

After I've done this I try to save the data is a new edited wave file by doing the following:

```
foo = []
for sample in edited_samples:
    foo.append(struct.pack('<h', int(sample)))

with open(fileIn.name + ' edited.wav', 'w') as file_out:
    file_out.write('RIFF')
    file_out.write(struct.pack('<L', riffLength))
    file_out.write('WAVE')
    file_out.write(ur'fmt\u0020')
    file_out.write(struct.pack('<H', fmt))
    file_out.write(struct.pack('<H', numChannels))
    file_out.write(struct.pack('<L', sampleRate))
    file_out.write(struct.pack('<L', byteRate))
    file_out.write(struct.pack('<H', blockAlign))
    file_out.write(struct.pack('<H', bitsPerSample))
    file_out.write('data')
    for item in foo:
        file_out.write(item)
```

While it doesn't give me any errors I can't play the new wave file in a media player. When I try open my new wave file I get a crash on the line `fmt, numChannels, sampleRate, byteRate, blockAlign, bitsPerSample = struct.unpack('<HHLLHH', fmtData)` with the error `error: unpack requires a string argument of length 16`. I imagine I'm building the wave file wrong. How do I build it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're intent on writing the support for .wav files yourself for some other reason (getting experience with dealing with binary files, etc.), don't do this. Python comes with the [`wave`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/wave.html) module that handles all of the file format issues and lets you just work with the data.

Comment: I can't use the wave library sadly as my project manager wants me to extend this project later to work with ECG files which are similar to audio files. It has to be done with binary, sadly.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, then. Pretty sure *that* doesn't come in the standard lib. :)